# Validate or verify is the correct term?

Tags: terminology

With my team we are trying to agree on some common terminology, conventions etc. for a new testing scheme. We are mostly done, however we can't agree on whether `verify` or `validate` is the better term for *checking if something is as specified*.

Which term should be used to describe the action?

Why are we debating on this?
Here are the Oxford Dictionary's definitions:

**verify**:

> make sure or demonstrate that (something) is true, accurate, or justified

**validate**:

> check or prove the validity or accuracy of [something]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on a very short Google research I would vote on **verify**. Validation is more for assumptions, you validate a hypothesis for example.

Maybe you get your hands on the BABOK V3 (Business Analysis Body of Knowledge):

It [contains topics](https://business-analysis-excellence.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/06/babok_v3.pdf) called:

- How to verify your requirements?
- What is validating requirements?

Which reads something like this (if I have to believe comments on the internet):

> **Verify Requirements**: ensures that a set of requirements or designs has
>   been developed in enough detail to be usable by a particular
>   stakeholder, is internally consistent, and is of high quality.
>
> **Validate Requirements**: ensures that a set of requirements or designs
>   delivers business value and supports the organization’s goals and
>   objectives.
>
> Comment from: http://enfocussolutions.com/requirements-verification-and-validation/

Maybe just throw a dice, that is a how I sometimes solve decisions that are stuck ;-)

Answer (score 0):

As per what I have read in the Wiki, verification refers to making sure that the product meets a set of design specifications.On the other hand validation means that the product meets the operational needs of the user.

So when we use a term to describe "if something is as specified",  verification will be a better choice.

Refer: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Verification_and_validation